# nginx returning index.html for js with 304 response

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server that is showing a 200 response in my browser for requests like

`https://server.com/app/static/js/2.8cc049f3.chunk.js`

and showing a 304 on the server logs

`"GET /static/js/2.8cc049f3.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://server.com/app"`

There is another nginx in front of the nginx running on `server.com` that is removing the `app` from the path. Based on the nginx logs on `server.com` this is working correctly. The `static` folder is in my root `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

The content my browser receives for the `js` file is the `index.html`. However when I login to the server and run

`curl http://localhost/static/js/2.8cc049f3.chunk.js`

I get the correct `js` content in response and in the logs the server prints 200

`"GET /static/js/2.8cc049f3.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1570391 "-" "curl/7.80.0" "-"`

Here is my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen  80;
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index   index.html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(static)/  {
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_types
            text/plain
            text/xml
            text/css
            text/comma-separated-values
            text/javascript application/x-javascript
            application/atom+xml;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

I've read that a 304 means the file hasn't changed and tells your browser to use its local cache, so I cleared my browser cache. I also restarted nginx, thinking that the first request would give a 200 response on the server but it was still a 304.

Based on the local curl request being successful I don't think there is anything wrong with my `nginx.conf`. I don't know if nginx somehow has the `index.html` cached as the content of my `js`, or if I didn't clear my browser cache correctly.

I'm also confused why the response code is 304 on the server but 200 in my browser.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but why do you use regex `location ~ ^/(static)/ { ... }` instead of prefix `location /static/ { ... }`? Being an equal in functionality, the second one will be more performant.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP `304` says "Not-Modified". This is because you are using another NGINX Proxy server in front of the NGINX Server we are talking about.

The 1st NGINX is requesting a resource on the 2nd NGINX and this one answers "Hey that file was not modified since the last time you have asked".

In this case it would be very helpful to check the configuration of the 1st NGINX Proxy instance or your turn of the caching in the first one and `proxy_cache off;` and check the result.